# How to create a dynamic type in children class, and assign it?

Tags: c#

At first, I have a parent class like:

```
public class Father {
  // skip ...
}
```

And these are two classes that inherit from `Father`. But `Method_A` only belongs to `Child_A` instead of `Child_B`.

```
public class Child_A : Father {
  // skip ...

  public void Method_A { ... }
}


public class Child_B : Father {
  // skip ...
}
```

Finally, I try to create a variable can be assigned dynamically to

```
public class MyClass {
  public Father dynamicObject;

  public void MyMethod {
    dynamicObject = new Child_A(); // Sometimes will be `Child_B`.

    if (...) {                     // only `Child_A` can pass, I promise
      dynamicObject.Method_A();    // Error here.
    }
  }
```

The error like below:

> Type 'Father' does not contain a definition for 'Method_A' and no extension method 'Method_A' of type 'Father' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

---

I had tried `var` type for `dynamicObject`, but we must set the `var` type in local scope.

```
public class MyClass {
  public var dynamicObject; // It's not allow.
  // ...
}
```

Comment: have you tried `ExpandoObject` https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cast to check the type of the `dynamicObject`:

```
Child_A childA = dynamicObject as Child_A;
if (childA != null) 
{               
    childA.Method_A(); 
}
```

or with `C# 6` and Null-conditional operator:

```
Child_A childA = dynamicObject as Child_A;             
childA?.Method_A();
```

also `is` with an explicit `(Child_A)` cast could be used but I prefer the first approach.

```
if (dynamicObject is Child_A) {
   ((Child_A)dynamicObject).Method_A();
}
```

with `C#7` and Pattern Matching like @Zbigniew suggested:

```
if (dynamicObject is Child_A child) {
   child.Method_A();
}
```

Comment: I would add C# 7 pattern matching solution here. More info: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/20/new-features-in-c-sharp-7/

Comment: @Zbigniew I updated my answer, is this what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, it would be even more useful when having more types and then use  'switch' clause

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
dynamicObject.Method_A();
```

by

```
((Child_A)dynamicObject).Method_A();
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing, It makes more sense to use the Method_A over the interface. while  number of methods and classes increases, it will be easier to manage

```
    public class Father { }
    public class Child_A : Father, IMethodOwner { public void Method_A() { }}
    public class Child_B : Father{ }
    public interface IMethodOwner { void Method_A(); }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Father dynamicObject;
        public void MyMethod() {
            var obj = dynamicObject as IMethodOwner;
            if(obj != null)
                obj.Method_A();
        }
    }
```